# How to find duplicate foreign keys against a record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, one for patients, and one for referrals.  On the patient table, we have patientNo field and a referralId field.  For this table, the referralId field should only ever be against one patientNo.  So we have the following table:

```
PatientNo  |  ReferralId
---------  |  ----------
1          |  1
1          |  2
1          |  3
2          |  4
```

This is how it should look, it's a one to many, one patient may have multiple referrals against it, but each referral may only have one patient, and once a referral is assigned to a patient, it should exist against any other patients.

The problem is, we've discovered that there are some referrals that are present against multiple patients, eg:

```
PatientNo  |  ReferralId
---------  |  ----------
1          |  1
1          |  2
1          |  3
2          |  1
```

So in this example, ReferralId 1 is against patient 1 *and* patient 2, which is not allowed.

My question is, what query could I run that could identify all of these referrals that have more than one patient?  I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: If it is "not allowed", then why is there no constraint to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the referrals, you can use aggregation:

```
select referralid
from patient_referrals pr
group by referralid
having min(patientid) <> max(patientid);
```

However, if you wanted the list of original rows where there are duplicates, I would recommend `exists`:

```
select pr.*
from patient_referrals pr
where exists (select 1
              from patient_referrals pr2
              where pr2.referralid = pr.referralid and
                    pr2.patientid <> pr.patientid
             );
```

After fixing this, you should fix your data model.  Probably the best approach is to just add a `patientid` to the `referrals` table and to dispense with the association table.  There is no need for one, if you don't have an n-m relationship.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I know the data structure is incorrect, but it's a 10 year old system that I've inherited, there's little chance of me being able to restructure anything without major ramifications.

Comment: @necrofish666 . . . In that case, you should put a unique constraint/index on that table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ReferralId
from Referrals
group by ReferralId
having count(PatientNo) > 1
```

Or you should use this:

```
select ReferralId, count(distinct PatientNo) num_of_diff_patients
from Referrals
group by ReferralId
having count(distinct PatientNo) > 1
```

Where you count the distinct patients in case you have data like:

```
PatientNo  |  ReferralId
---------  |  ----------
1          |  1
1          |  1
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=208d7c0d5ceee3b404a828496523bf51)